# Yaml and Expression Language

Tags: php, symfony

I can use the Expression Language (EL) in the xml files by just indicating the type of the parameter being expression.

However, I can't indicate this type in yml files. According to this article:

https://knpuniversity.com/blog/service-expressions

theoretically I should be able to access the Expression Language easily, like this:

```
arguments:
        - "@=service('doctrine').getRepository('AppBundle:User')"
```

I suppose the EL should be executed BEFORE the configuration is read, validated and passed into the final object. But it's not: the expression is apparently never evaluated by EL in yml files, like the one above.

What should I do to use EL in yml files? Could it be that I myself wrote the config validation (see: semantic configuration for bundles) and should I add an expectation to be not only just a scalar value, but also an expression?

When dumping the got value from this config, I see the string with the literal value, with the  example as above it is: `@=service('doctrine').getRepository('AppBundle:User')`

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Still did not find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available for `yml` files as well as should work out of the box.

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html

Maybe check your Symfony version...

Comment: It's 2.7 / 2.8.

Comment: Then it should work http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/service_container/expression_language.html

Comment: It works for xml files, as I mentioned. But wherever I put "@=...." part in the yml config files, say parameters.yml, it is treated like it was just a string. If I want it to be an expression, I must myself manually inject the Expression Language into the final object, and evaluate this string there... which is something I don't want, as I expect Symfony to automate evaluating the expressions for yml, just like for xml, files.

Comment: Can you show your yaml file? I'm actually using these expressions myself in  yaml's with Symfony3

Comment: At the moment I just stumbled upon this problem - so far I used it for a random setting (to check it), where a bundle - say SonataAdmin - expected a string. I also checked it in several other places / settings in config.yml, I thought it'd work like it did in xml files (where I explicitly indicated a type as expression)...